# Encrypted Data on a SQL Server to be decrypted on an oracle server without having a linked server connection back to the SQL Server from Oracle

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, encryption

So here's my scenario:

1. We have a SQL Server-2016 where ColumnA data is encrypted with AES-256.
2. We export this data to an excel sheet or a flat-file or whatever.
3. Then import this file to an external out of network Oracle 12c Server table.
4. Remember, the ColumnA data is still encrypted on the Oracle Server.
5. Is there a way to do an on-the-fly decryption of this data on the Oracle Server without connecting back to the SQL Server without using another program like Java etc.

How is this accomplished?
Does the Oracle server import/can we transfer the generated Symmetric key, certificate somehow into Oracle so we can do a query on the Oracle server with a function that decrypts the encrypted data?

Comment: What performs the encryption in SQL Server? Is the application inserting encrypted data, or is the data encrypted at rest by SQL Server?

Comment: I created a Database Master Key, Certificate and Symmetric key with AES 256 encryption by that certificate, then use the Encryptbykey function to encrypt the column in SQL Server.

Comment: I don't believe that Oracle would be able to decrypt that natively. You would need to recreate all of the SQL Server functionality with custom PL/SQL code in Oracle, which I suspect is not a realistic approach. I don't see a way to do what you are proposing.

Comment: Reading a little more - even if you could duplicate the encryption algorithm with the DBMS_CRYPTO package exactly you would still have to provide the private encryption key, which only lives on your SQL Server. Distributing that key would allow anyone to decrypt your data and defeat the entire purpose. Could you place the decrypted data into a separately encrypted dump file of some kind (password protected?) that could be unlocked and loaded into Oracle, then use Oracle's DBMS_CRYPTO to protect the data with a different set of keys?